# Django syncdb custom name for table

Tags: django

`manage.py syncdb` creates db tables for the models in form `appname_modelname`.How can i make manage.py to create tables in the format just `modelname`?

is the only way is to add `class Meta:
    db_table = u'modelname'`

Comment: I'm not sure but south might do that.

Comment: It's not about south creating tables, but also as for django using them. So yes and no. There are always some ways to overcome it, but safe and well documented way is only that one inside vanilla django as far as I know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the only way to change the name of the created table is to set db_table to the inner Meta class.

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#table-names.

---

However, with some metaclass magic, it is actually possible to do what you are looking for. This example is just to show that it is possible since Python is such a nice language. It can break with newer releases (even though unlikely) of Django since ModelBase and _meta is not officially documented AFAIK. I would just stick with adding db_table manually in your models.

By creating a custom metaclass that constructs the model classes it is possible to change the db_table attribute on the inner meta class.

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.base import ModelBase

class ModelWithoutAppNameBase(ModelBase):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        model = super(ModelWithoutAppNameBase, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)
        model._meta.db_table = name.lower()
        return model


class ModelWithoutAppName(models.Model):
    __metaclass__ = ModelWithoutAppNameBase
```

You then inherit from `ModelWithoutAppName` instead of `django.db.models.Model` when you create your models:

```
class YourModel(ModelWithoutAppName):  # database table name will be yourmodel
   foo = models.IntegerField()
```